# Referring to a child input field using @this in f:ajax with enclosing composite component

Tags: jsf, mojarra

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.3.17 with the following page content:

```
<dcoco:modul id="login" name="Login">
  <h:form id="form" prependId="true">
    <h:outputLabel id="idLoginUsernameLabel" value="Name:" />
    <h:inputText id="idLoginUsername" value="#{loginForm.username}">
      <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="idUserOutput" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:panelGroup id="idUserOutput">#{loginForm.username}</h:panelGroup>
  </h:form>
</dcoco:modul>
```

With the following definition of the composite component:

```
<cc:interface>
  <cc:attribute name="name" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
  <h:panelGroup>
    <h1>#{cc.attrs.name}</h1>
    <cc:insertChildren />
  </h:panelGroup>
</cc:implementation>
```

When leaving the input field, `idUserOutput` is not updated as I would have expected. I think this is because the corresponding JS renders as follows (I am using "_" as separator char):

```
onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'change','login','login_form_idUserOutput')"
```

Which uses the ID of the composite component and not the ID of the input field in the fourth parameter.

If I change any of the following, it works:

- `execute="idLoginUsername"`
- remove the composite component
- revert to Mojarra 2.3.14

Did the rendering behaviour of `@this` change with the new Mojarra version? What do I have to change to refer to the input field in `f:ajax` (I cannot use the ID of the input field in my real-world application)?

Comment: as far I know: the execute attribute of `<f:ajax>` already defaults to `@this`.So, no need to add `execute="@this"`. try to remove this attribute and check.

Comment: yes this is correct - and it would work, too. But since other parts of my real world application default to ```@form```, I would prefer to explicitly specify something (besides having to change and test a lot input fields if I would remove the attribute). And this also seems like a workaround to me. Is it possibly a bug in Mojarra?

Comment: I see this bug already fixed in release 2.3.15. Ref:https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/pull/4915.

Comment: Oh, I think this bug already raised here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/5032.